# set tab pages on left side of tab continer in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, tabcontrol, tabcontainer

I want to ask you about tab containers. Is there any way to set tab pages vertically on left side of tab container. some kind of vertical tab...

**Example**

> tabheader
>   tabheader (active tab) --- content

Comment: Could you evaluate just a tiny bit? It is hard to gasp what you are trying to do.

Comment: @FilipEkberg i edited as i can

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others?  If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer.  It may seem strange, but it is preferred to deleting in situations like this.

Comment: i gave up using vertical tab so its not this question's answer if nessary i can tell im using modal popup instead of verticaltab

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about ASP.Net Ajax Tabcontainer?
If so, have a look at following link: [Making the AjaxToolKit TabContainer tabs vertical](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2008/02/making-ajaxtoolkit-tabcontainer-tabs.html)

The guy used simple css to get the TabContainer showing vertcal instead of horizontal.

Comment: thx alot but not exactly i want... it sets tab headers top of the tabpages but i wanna set left side of pages...